# Add animation to SnackBar in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-snackbar

The last update support library `24.2.1` has disabled animations when  `show` or `close` snackbar.

How is it possible to have animations again?

**Test:**

- Android 5 Lollipop, animations NONE, need enter to accessibility device settings after that works
- Android 6 M, animations OK

Comment: i am using too `compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.1'` it still showing default animation

Comment: @Viks in Lollipop are disabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the reason why this is happening, but not how to fix yet.

```
/**
 * Returns true if we should animate the Snackbar view in/out.
 */
private boolean shouldAnimate() {
    return !mAccessibilityManager.isEnabled();
}
```

That is called by Snackbar class and is false on working devices, and true on devices not working. Does anyone know about this?

So after i disabled lastpass in my system settings, accessibility the snackbar now animates as it should. That is crazy how that works. Nova launcher has the same affect. I guess any service in accessibility that is enabled will cause the snackbar animation to not work.

Comment: Runs perfectly after entering accessibility, that rarest thing